# Pthreads array block distribution

Tags: c, arrays, pthreads, iteration

Working on a project for school in C using Pthreads to break down a one dimensional array into sub matrices of tRows and tCols. The overall array will be of the size wRows and wCols. Let's say wCols = 4, wRows = 4, tCols = 2, and tRows = 2.  If input of the array is integers 1-16 we would have the grid of:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
1314 15 17

Thus Thread 0 would process the subgrid
1 2 
5 6

Thread 1
3 4
7 8 

Thread 2 
9  10
13 14

Thread 3
11 12
15 17
```

How would I go about iterating through the one dimensional array to get these values based on which Thread is being used using two for loops? 
I feel like I need to calculate a start and finish for both threads, but I am completely stuck with this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What if the dimension is not divisible eqaully? E.g. how do you split if Wcols=5 and wRows=3 ?

Comment: @l3x It will always be evenly divisible.

Comment: The number of threads is also vary depending on the number of grids?

Comment: @l3x the number of threads will always be ( wRows * wCols ) / ( tRows * tCols )

Answer (score 1):

The fourth argument of `pthread_create()` is forwarded to the thread start function as its argument.  The purpose of this is to pass any necessary thread-specific data to the thread, such as, for example, the starting row and column of its patch of the matrix.

In this case, it would be particularly clean to pass through to each thread a pointer to the top-, left-most element of its matrix patch.  Supposing that the size of the patch and the number of columns in the matrix is known to every thread, that's enough for it to determine the row and column numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it (which does make use of the fourth argument, as described in the first answer):

```
- (void)main {
    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.getAssetCount; index++) {
        dispatch_queue_t threadQueue = dispatch_queue_create([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"threadQueue %ld", index] UTF8String], DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
        dispatch_async(threadQueue, ^{
            pthread_t thread_tid;
            pthread_attr_t attr;
            int            returnVal;

            // init and check if init a new thread successful
            returnVal = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
            assert(!returnVal);

            // set attribute detach state for new thread
            returnVal = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
            assert(!returnVal);

            // create and run the new thread
            int threadError = pthread_create_from_mach_thread(&thread_tid, &attr, &ThreadMethod, (void*)index);
            returnVal = pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
            assert(!returnVal);
            if (threadError != 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"Thread error: %i", threadError);
                // Report an error.
            }
        });
        //NSLog(@"index: %ld", index);
        index = index + 4;
    }
}

void* ThreadMethod(void *arg)
{
    for (NSInteger loop = 0; loop < 4. ; loop++) {
        NSInteger index = (NSInteger)arg + loop;
        NSLog(@"index: %ld", index);

        [AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.imageManager requestAVAssetForVideo:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults[(NSInteger)index] options:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.videoOptions resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            if(![[info objectForKey:PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] boolValue]) {
                if (asset) {
                    NSError __autoreleasing *error = nil;
                    AVAssetReader *reader;
                    [reader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:asset error:&error] addOutput:[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:[[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] outputSettings:@{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA), (id)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey  : @([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / (int)floor(sqrt([AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate getAssetCount]))), (id)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey : @(([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / (int)floor(sqrt([AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate getAssetCount]))) * (9.0/16.0))}]];
                    [reader startReading];


                    while ([reader status] != AVAssetReaderStatusReading) { }
                    if ([reader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading) { NSLog(@"reader %ld reading", index); }
                    else { NSLog(@"reader %ld NOT reading", index); }
                    DisplayLayer *displayLayer = (DisplayLayer *)[[AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate consumers] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (NSInteger)index]];
                    dispatch_queue_t readerQueue = dispatch_queue_create([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"readerQueue %ld", (NSInteger)index] UTF8String], DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

                    [displayLayer requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:readerQueue usingBlock:^{
                        @autoreleasepool {
                            if ([reader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading) {
                                CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [[[reader outputs] firstObject] copyNextSampleBuffer];
                                if (sampleBuffer) {
                                    [displayLayer enqueueSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                                    /*OSStatus err = CMSimpleQueueEnqueue(displayLayer.simpleBuffer, sampleBuffer);
                                     if (err) {
                                     NSLog(@"Producer %ld buffer error: %d", index, (int)err);
                                     CMSimpleQueueReset(displayLayer.simpleBuffer);
                                     }*/
                                    CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
                                    sampleBuffer = nil;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }];
                }
            }
        }];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```